# How to display some information from csv file in Bash Ubuntu

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu-18.04

I have a csv file like this:

```
,2019 - October,,2019 - September,,2019 - August,
,Agricultural,Industrial,Agricultural,Industrial,Agricultural,Industrial
Toronto,86746,382958,55833,348182,49313,355977
Montreal,70718,605909,22084,549823,23428,641181
Calgary,231493,1420226,114937,1249378,114243,1189979
TOTAL,388957,2409093,192853,2147384,186984,2187137
```

I have to do a script to display some information from the file in this way:

```
2  388957  388957
3  2409093  2409093
.. ......   ....
```

For example, in the first line the number 2 corresponds to the column number (the display begins in column B), the next number corresponds to the sum of rows 3 to 5 of column B, and de last one corresponds to the number in TOTAL line. The second line is the same bout done with column C, and so on from column B to column G.

How could I do this in Bash Ubuntu?

I've tried to do this, but it isn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUTFILE="/media/exports.csv"
FIELD=2
COUNT=`sed 's/[^,]//g' $INPUTFILE | wc -c`; let "COUNT+=1"
while [ "$FIELD" -lt "$COUNT" ]; do
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";sum=0}{if(NR>=3&&NR<=5)sum=sum+$FIELD}END{print$FIELD,sum, (tail -1), "\n"
}' /media/exports.csv
let "FIELD+=1"
done
```

Running this script, the information displays like this:

```
TOTAL,388957,2409093,192853,2147384,186984,2187137 0 -1
```

This result is repeated many times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do not post pictures of text, post the `.csv` data itself. We can't run an image through a shell-script to verify any solution and we are not going to re-type it for you.

Comment: If you have two problems, please post two questions.